# Unable to convert JavaScript injection pattern to TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

We use a bespoke injection pattern in a rather large vanilla JavaScript application (more a framework with many consumers). The pattern allows us to be explicit about what dependencies each JS module takes. This is beneficial for two main reasons: it is easy to stub dependencies when unit testing a module and it allows our consumers to dynamically replace module implementations at runtime.

We have started migrating all of our modules over to TypeScript but have run into trouble converting a few modules that expose custom types. The problem is that TypeScript seems to want custom types to be exported immediately but we actually want to export the type after supplying the runtime dependencies via a function call (our dependency injection pattern).

**So the question is how can we convert the following injection pattern to TypeScript without compromising the pattern itself?**

```js
module.exports = function ContextModule(logger)  {
  var log = logger.register('context');

  function Context() {
    log('creating type');
  }

  Context.prototype = {
    doSomething: function() {
      log('doing something');
    }
  }

  Context.doSomethingStatic = function() {
    log('doing something static');
  }

  return Context;
};
```

We return the custom type and can then new it up when we need to. For example, we might compose the above highly contrived module in a main.js as follows:

```js
var loggerModule = require('LoggerModule.js');
var contextModule = require('ContextModule.js');

logger = loggerModule();
var Context = contextModule(logger);

// then we might use the Context type
var context = new Context();
context.doSomething();       // instance method
Context.doSomethingStatic(); // static method
```

Note the following:

- the logger module is injected into the context module
- the logger module methods are then used in the ContextModule function directly or in the "class" implementation it is defining
- we use CommonJs to "require in" the module files and browserify to combine them

Answer (score 0):

> So the question is how can we convert the following injection pattern to TypeScript without compromising the pattern itself

You can definitely use it as it is (JavaScript is valid TypeScript). If you want safety, the process to convert the injection framework to TypeScript idioms is going to be more hard than just using one designed for it.

I highly recommend https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I have been considering leaving it in JavaScript so that is definitely a fallback - probably just create an interface or when we inject it into other TypeScript modules. I was more trying to determine if there is a trick in TypeScript to make this work. 

As for Inversify, because this is a framework we have avoided taking on dependencies on other libraries. That said, I will check out the library in more detail. Thanks